# Dynamic webtable rows storing, searching and handling with java webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, collections, enums, hashmap

There are several solution, but nothing with hashmap and enum.

Website table element simple tbody, tr,td. The code below, I have webelements in the rows list, or the row data as a string in the other list.

```
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        List<ArrayList<String>> rowsData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        for(WebElement row:rows){
            List<WebElement> rowElements = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

            ArrayList<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(WebElement column:rowElements){
                rowData.add(column.getText().toString());
            }

            rowsData.add(rowData);
        }
```

One row can be: 
12, ab, apple, red, -1000;
66, ac, grape, blue, 1000; etc.

I have to check all the rows and find the first row which is red, apple and last row is not bigger than 0 and click.

More useful option can be enum and hashmap. Hashmap keys can be enum values, like ID, NAME, FRUIT, COLOR, NUMBER. Checking hashmap has COLOR= red, name = apple etc.

Any solution for this? I think it can be very useful for everybody!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought of creating row as an object? So something like this

```
public class Fruit {
   private String name;
   private int id;
   //go horizontally with your column names;
   //have getters/setters here
}
```

Now your code could be written slightly differently like,

```
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

for(WebElement row:rows){
     List<WebElement> rowElements = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
     Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
     //you know first column is name or so on
     //or store column header order and use it here
     fruit.setName(rowElements.get(0).getText()); 
     fruit.id(rowElements.get(1).getText());
     fruits.add(fruit);
}
```

Now you can iterate over `fruits`

Comment: Make sense to me and it is the solution with some streams, parser etc. Thanks for the good idea nilesh!

Comment: glad it helped @brobee

Comment: nilesh, have you implemented a parser for webtable? This solution is ok, but I have lots of pages and I wanna put into hashmap because it would easier to use. Thanks!

Comment: You would have to develop something generic in that case and use it as a library

Comment: yeah I know, but lack of experience. Any article, sample code would be appreciated..